# Retrieving multiple rows with Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-postgres

I am beginning to learn SequelizeJs however I encounter a small issue:
I have a model which is defined as such:

```
var ex_table= sequelize.define("ex_table", {
   concept1: Sequelize.STRING(5),
   concept2: Sequelize.STRING(80),
   concept3: Sequelize.STRING,
   weight: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   value: Sequelize.DECIMAL(20,2)
}, {
   tableName: "samble_table"});
```

Retrieving a single row from the table works, I do it like this:

```
ex_table
  .find({where: Sequelize.and({weight: 320193}, {concept1: 'AGLOK'}, {concept2: 'lambda'}, {concept2: 'Industry Group'})})
  .complete(function (err, result) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log("An error occurred while creating the table:", err);
    } else {
      console.log(result.values);
    }
  })
```

This gives me one row of data, which is as expected.
However when I'm trying to retrieve multiple rows like this:

```
ex_table
  .findAll({where: Sequelize.and({weight: 320193}, {concept1: 'AGLOK'}, {concept2: 'lambda'}, {concept2: 'Industry Group'})})
  .complete(function (err, result) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log("An error occurred while creating the table:", err);
    } else {
      console.log(result.values);
    }
  })
```

Here I get underfined, any ideas how to get the multiple rows?

Comment: Isn't `result` an array in the `findAll` case?

Comment: @barry-johnson Indeed it is an array, I was confused as I thought I had to do something with result.rows or result.values, I found out the solution, I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I found out, that there are at least 2 ways to get all the rows:
As commented by @barry-johnson, result is an array so we go over the array like any other:

```
ex_table
  .findAll({where: Sequelize.and({weight: 320193}, {concept1: 'AGLOK'}, {concept2: 'lambda'}, {concept2: 'Industry Group'})})
  .complete(function (err, result) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log("An error occurred while creating the table:", err);
    } else {
      for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
           console.log(result[i].values);
           }
    }
  })
```

or there is this interesting line on raw queries in the Models part of Sequelize documentation:

> Sometimes you might be expecting a massive dataset that you just want
>   to display, without manipulation. For each row you select, Sequelize
>   creates a DAO, with functions for update, delete, get associations etc.
>   If you have thousands of rows, this might take some time. If you only
>   need the raw data and don't want to update anything, you can do like
>   this to get the raw data.

As I wanted to see the raw data, this is what we need, so we can get the multiple rows like this:

```
ex_table
  .findAll({where: Sequelize.and({weight: 320193}, {concept1: 'AGLOK'}, {concept2: 'lambda'}, {concept2: 'Industry Group'})}, {raw:true})
  .complete(function (err, result) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log("An error occurred while creating the table:", err);
    } else {
           console.log(result);
    }
  })
```

Hopefully this will help someone else as well.